# Why I always get null for the output in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

In this code, it always output NULL (without any data, despite they have the data). I'm trying to get id_cust,lastName,addRess from 2 table (customer and order_status). Can anyone help me? Im new in SQL.

```
delimiter //
#drop procedure if exists  GetOrderStatus 
create procedure GetOrderStatus(IN id_cust INT, 
                                OUT lastName VARCHAR(45),
                                OUT o_number INT,
                                OUT addRess VARCHAR(45))
begin
declare id_cust INT;
declare lastName VARCHAR(45);
declare addRess VARCHAR(45);
declare ci_ty VARCHAR(45);
declare dscrption VARCHAR(45);
declare o_number INT;
declare order_stts VARCHAR(45);
declare total_item INT;
declare reMarks VARCHAR(45);

declare curs cursor for 
select c.c_id,o.order_no,o.o_status,o.item_total,c.description,o.remarks,c.lname
from order_status o, customer c; 
open curs;
fetch curs into id_cust,o_number,order_stts,total_item,dscrption,reMarks,lastName;

select id_cust,lastName,addRess from customer
where id_cust > 2
and customer.id_cust = order_status.id_cust;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    create procedure GetOrderStatus(IN id_cust INT, 
                                OUT olastName VARCHAR(45),
                                OUT out_number INT,
                                OUT oaddRess VARCHAR(45))
begin

select c.c_id, c.lname, c.address 
INTO id_cust, olastName, oaddRess from customer AS c
JOIN order_status AS o -- JOIN the customers and orders table together based on cust num
ON c.id_cust = o.id_cust
where c.c_id=id_cust;
end
```

I think you were way off. There was no need to use a cursor at all, just a simple JOIN between two tables based on customer id. I'm guessing that you have an address field in the customers table, that's why you'll see the `@addRess=c.address`
I'm guessing that this function is supposed to get order status based on order number. Also, for the parameters that are outputs there is no need to declare a seperate variable to store them. Simply store them in the passed in output variables `@nameOfOutputVariable=someValue 

Let me know if this doesn't make sense,

Sean

Comment: why do you putthe word 'OUTPUT' at  @addRess VARCHAR(45) OUTPUT? Please explain to me..

Comment: why does sql saying that i'm having error code 1064 on line 1 which is "create procedure GetOrderStatus(@id_cust INT,..."

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using T_SQL but you are using MySQL. I have modified the SQL appropriately.